# Inverse z-Transformation and impulse response

Tags: z-transform

I have a question regarding a pole zero plot and I want to compute the impulse response with the inverse z-Transform.

From the pole zero plot I could extract:

$$H(z) = \frac{z+1}{(z-0.6i)(z+0.6i)}$$

How can I get $h[n]$?

If I use partial fraction expansion I get something complex for $A_1$ and $A_2$ and that doesn't make sense, at least to me.

Comment: $H(z) = \overline{H(\overline{z})}$ thus $h(n)$ is real, i.e. $A_1 = \overline{A_2}$. and on $l_1(\mathbb{N})$ the Z-transform is injective, so there are not 2 different $h(n)$ for a same $H(z)$

Comment: @user1952009 sorry, but what s the $H(z)$ with the bar over it? And what's $l_1$?

Comment: $\overline{z}$ is the complex conjugate, while $h \in l_1(\mathbb{N})$ means that $h(n) = 0$ when $n < 0$ and that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |h(n)| < \infty$. this is an important condition since $\frac{1}{1-z^{-1}} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{-n} = - \sum_{n=-1}^{-\infty} z^{-n}$ where the last series is the Z-transform of a sequence $\not\in l_1(\mathbb{N})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial fractions will work and the end result will be real valued:

$$H(z)=\frac{Az}{z-0.6i}+\frac{A^*z}{z+0.6i}\tag{1}$$

where $A=0.5-i\cdot 5/6$, and $^*$ denotes complex conjugation. The inverse $\mathcal{Z}$-transform of $(1)$ is

$$\begin{align}h[n]&=\left[A(0.6i)^n+A^*(-0.6i)^n\right]u[n]\\&=\left[A(0.6)^ne^{in\pi/2}+A^*(0.6)^ne^{-in\pi/2}\right]u[n]\\&=2\,\text{Re}\left\{A(0.6)^ne^{in\pi/2}\right\}u[n]\\&=2(0.6)^n|A|\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}+\arg(A)\right)\tag{2}\end{align}$$

which is real-valued, as it should be.